# PDF to HTML via API or through ColdFusion?

Tags: html, css, pdf, coldfusion

This has been asked many times, i'm sure, but i was curious if it's possible to upload a PDF to some site, keep it private, and get back HTML/CSS? Or, is there a way with ColdFusion to do this? It needs to be damn near the same as the PDF. I heard through a developer at a hackathon there was a PDF converter that uses the Webkit engine, but i wasn't sure where to find that or how it worked.

Thanks in advance (and no, i have to use coldfusion)!

Comment: CF can do PDF -> image via the thumbnail function, but not to HTML/CSS.

Comment: Awesome, im not the CF programmer thats just what they are using, could you tell me or show me a link to this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may generate an Image of PDF using `<cfpdf>` (for ColdFusion 8 or above)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html

```
<!--- Generate thumbnails from pages in a PDF document --->
<cfpdf
    required
    action = "thumbnail"
    source = "absolute or relative pathname to a PDF file|PDF document variable|
        cfdocument variable"
    optional
    destination = "directory path where the thumbnail images are written"
    format = "png|jpeg|tiff"
    imagePrefix = "string used as a prefix in the output filename"
    overwrite = "yes|no"
    password = "PDF source file password"
    pages = "page or pages to make into thumbnails"
    resolution= "low|high"
    scale = "percentage between 1 and 100"
    transparent = "yes|no">
```

FYI, `<cfpdf>` is currently powered by [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: Awesome :) this will be perfect so i can talk to them about it. Right now our web site is over 50% PDFs and i don't know CF (im going to training to learn CF tho) but until then I wanted to push towards a non-PDF website

Comment: or convert the PDFs into HTML+CSS yourself by hand.  Don't even need ColdFusion.